How to enforce strict CPU frequency control in userspace?
I’m developing a tool that requires complete control over CPU frequencies on my system, but I'm running into issues with maintaining the desired frequencies. Specifically, I'm using the cpufreq-set commandline tool to set the CPU frequency, but I’ve noticed the following behavior:

The system treats the frequency I set as more of a guideline rather
than a strict limit.
After a few seconds, the frequency often fluctuates and eventually
settles on something different, completely disregarding my set
value.

I would like the CPU to strictly adhere to the frequency I specify without allowing the system to override it. I’ve tried various governors (userspace, performance) and configuration options, but the issue persists. Is there a way to enforce strict CPU frequency control in userspace, or are there alternative methods/tools for achieving this level of control?
I am running Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on a Lenovo Ideapad 3 with an AMD Ryzen 5 4500U.
Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Have a look at this answer and this answer
